# I want to check the server.When I tried to run the code in console using:Node server.js, it didn't run the code. Any ideas why?

Tags: node.js, server

***I want to check the server.When I tried to run the code in console using:Node server.js, it  didn't run the code. Any ideas why?***

**This is my code where I tried to check the server**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

 app.get("/", function(request, response){
   console.log(request);
 })
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**and here I try to run the code in console, and it simply doesn't do anything: it shows me the location and that's all**

Helens-MacBook-Pro:my-express-server helenmyrlen$ node server.js
Helens-MacBook-Pro:my-express-server helenmyrlen$

Comment: Code is perfectly fine and it should print the server started logs

Comment: What is the output on the console? there is no error in the code. And have you installed node and express?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to NodeJS so I can't find where you are doing are but you can try with the below script. It works.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Run the app with the following command:

$ node app.js
Then, load http://localhost:3000/ in a browser to see the output.

Comment: Thank you, but still doesn't work,  guess it may be because of VPN